# Python - WTForms datetime occurs str

Tags: python, jinja2, wtforms

I am wondering why I am getting error in jinja2:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Even though datetime object has strftime():

```
order_date = DateField("Payment Date up to:", format="%Y-%m-%d", default=(datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=60)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

So, somehow it returns 'str' in `datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=60)`

Could you, please, help me, how to fix this error and why it occured?

P.s. code in html:

```
<div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-provide="datepicker" autocomplete="off"
    class="form-control pull-right input-sm" name="order_date" id="order_date"
    placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" value="{{cd.form.order_date.data}}" title="Default value is Now + 60 days">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the complete error traceback…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strftime()` returns a string. and DateField is expecting a datetime object based on the format line.

```
order_date = DateField("Payment Date up to:", format="%Y-%m-%d", default=datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=60))
order_date = order_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```